# where is memory leak in this code c++ opencv?

Tags: memory-management, opencv, memory-leaks

this is the code

```
CvMemStorage *mem123 = cvCreateMemStorage(0);
CvSeq* ptr123;CvRect face_rect123;
CvHaarClassifierCascade* cascade123 = (CvHaarClassifierCascade*)cvLoad("haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml" );    //detects the face if it's frontal
void HeadDetection(IplImage* frame,CvRect* face){
    ptr123=cvHaarDetectObjects(frame,cascade123,mem123,1.2,2,CV_HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNING);
    if(!ptr123){return ;}
    if(!(ptr123->total)){return ;}
    face_rect123=*(CvRect*)cvGetSeqElem( ptr123, 0 );   //CvRect face_rect holds the position of Rectangle
    face->height=face_rect123.height;
    face->width=face_rect123.width;
    face->x=face_rect123.x;
    face->y=face_rect123.y;
    return ;
}//detects the position of head and it is fed in CvRect*face as rectangle
int main(){
    IplImage* oldframe=cvCreateImage(cvSize(640,480),8,3);
    CvCapture* capture=cvCaptureFromCAM(CV_CAP_ANY);
    CvRect a;a.height=0;a.width=0;a.x=0;a.y=0;
    while(1){

        oldframe=cvQueryFrame(capture); //real frame captured of size 640x480
        cvFlip(oldframe,oldframe,1);
        cvResize(oldframe,frame);   //frame scaled down 4 times 
        HeadDetection(frame,&a);
        cvShowImage("frame",frame);
        cvWaitKey(1);
    }
}
```

Here if "HeadDetection(frame,&a);" is commented, then using task manager i see that angledetection.exe (name of my project) consumes 20188 Kb memory (No memory leak happening then).

However if I don't comment that the taskmanager shows that some memory leak is happening (around 300Kb/s )

I'm using VS 2010 on 64 bit windows 7 bit OS (core 2 duo).

This code is trying to detect face and get the four corners of square by haar detection in OpenCV 2.1

In case anything is unclear please ask. :-)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried to use some memory leak tools but I was unable to get any progress (Anyhow it's a small code)

Answer (score 1):

You are getting a pointer to an object when you call `cvHaarDetectObjects`.

But you never free it ( the object that **ptr123** points to).

Also **face_rect123** isnt freed.

Btw you should consider refactoring the code and give better names to the variables.